# Scala - phantom - Saving blob to Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, blob, phantom-dsl

I'm looking to save a file to cassandra

I'm using Scala with websudos" % "phantom-dsl_2.10" % "1.4.0" driver

I think I've got my model created with

```
sealed class CassandraRepoBlob extends CassandraTable[CassandraRepoBlob, CassandraBlob] {
  object id extends UUIDColumn(this) with PrimaryKey[UUID]

  object blobby extends BlobColumn(this)
```

and this seems to expect a case class of

```
case class CassandraBlob(
                        blobby: java.nio.ByteBuffer
```

I haven't been able to find many examples; so just want to check if I'm on the right track?

From here I guess I need to read my File to a ByteBuffer and I should be good to go?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"From here I guess I need to read my File to a ByteBuffer and I should be good to go?"  Yes, When I used java to write rows with a column of type blob being file contents, I had to convert the file contents to a ByteBuffer  (really easy actually, ByteBuffer.wrap(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath())) in java).